# Help with manual partitioning while installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have Windows 11 and Ubuntu Desktop 23.10 in a dual boot. Now I want to completely reinstall Ubuntu while keeping Windows 11.  I have no idea what to do in the "manual partitioning" step of the installation. Please check the image. Could someone please provide a step by step guidance on what to do?[image]

Comment: You've not said what Ubuntu product (Server? Desktop? nor which installer you're asking about as there are 3 installers available for Ubuntu 23.10 (two choices for Desktop & one for Server)).  If your last system was on *nvme01n1p5* then you select it for `/` and just select your ESP if using uEFI boot (*your machine firmware will dictate which drive that's on*) & let it go. You don't select format if you want a non-destructive re-install but the effect differs if using Server or Desktop & you didn't specify.

Comment: It is Ubuntu Desktop 23.10. I edited my question to make it clear. I appreciate your answer (and it really helps me understand a bit what is going on) but I need more detailed instructions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

Comment: FYI:  As I stated in my first comment, Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop has two ISO choices which use different installers; the *primary* ISO uses `ubuntu-desktop-installer` where as the *alternate* (also called *legacy*) uses `ubiquity`. Thus how it appears will vary based on what Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop ISO you downloaded & use... What you do on both is the same, they just look *slightly* different (*you didn't specify which Ubuntu 23.10 Desktop ISO you're using, and may not have noticed the choices available at download*)

Comment: Thank you for clarrifying. I am using the primary installer (NOT the legacy one).

Comment: Using Something Else, choose p5 and change to make it / (root) and ext4. Check box to format. That is all you need as new user. If more experienced, then separate /home or data partitions may be additional choices, but you need to have some idea of how much data you will have in your /home, first.